# Using angular library in Stencil component

Tags: angular, stenciljs, angular-library, stencil-component

I know we can use the Stencil web components in Angular application. Is there any way we can use an Angular library in Stencil web component.

I have a library in Angular 14 which have all the common functions and utility functions. Is there any way to use the functions in this library from a Stencil web component.